# Combining two overlapping raster sets' attributes using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, runoff

I am ultimately trying to get a runoff curve number raster file. In order to determine the runoff curve number I need to know the soil's hydrologic group and the land use category.

I have two overlapping raster datasets of similar shape and extent - a soil raster with 10mx10m cell size that contains soil hydrologic group data and a land cover raster with 30mx30m cell size that contains land cover descriptions.

I want to take the soil raster's hydrologic group information and put that into the land cover raster's attribute file based on the overlapping location.

What tool can I use to accomplish this?

Edit - regarding the combine tool, here are my two tables:

Soil
[image]

LandCover
[image]

The two fields I am really interested in lining up are the Soil MUKEY field and the LandCover cls_desc_1 field. For LandCover the Value field can also be used as an identifier.

After using the combine tool, this is the attribute table I get:
[image]

As you can see none of the fields I want are in the new table so I can't join tables later on.

Comment: Try Combine tool

Comment: I've tried this one. Unfortunately, it doesn't combine the complete attribute tables it just takes the "cell value" of the second raster with no option to change which field I want to combine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try harder. Picture below shows tables of 2 rasters, - soil and land use:

[image]

Next one shows output of Combine tool:

[image]

Last picture shows above table updated with description of relevant soils and land use:

[image]

I use Add join to transfer descriptions to output of Combine tool.

Comment: mine's not coming across as anything like that. Are you using ArcGIS Pro? Check the original post for my edits with screenshots.

Comment: Did you read last line in my post?